# VLC: how to autostart streaming of audio from linein or mic in?

Tags: audio, vlc-media-player, streaming, microphone

I'm able to configure VLC manually to stream my microphone or my line-in input via http as an mp3 streaming. 
It works

Now I need to autostart this when windows starts, because my pc is here just for this, transmit a conference over internet.

I need to avoid user interaction to avoid problem wit VLC config.

**Is there a way ?**

I know there is A LOT of command line switches and params to use, but if I was able to understand which to use I wouldn't ask. So: **which command params must I use?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DOS vlc.exe --help emits a copious amount of help text but I am unable to redirect it to a file using all my tricks. Anyway, you can create a .cmd script that invokes vlc.exe with the necessary command line arguments and place that script in the Startup directory of the Start menu of the user expected to log in to the machine.

If this needs to run as a service regardless of user logins, then you will have to find some other approach.